# How do I transition vertically/upwards?

Tags: html, css

The below code works, but when mouse hover on the tab, the tab is vertically expanding downwards. How do I expand it upwards?

```css
ul.nav li a {
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
background: #cbcbcb ;
color: #174867;
padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
width: 50px;
height:100px;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
}

ul.nav li a:hover {
background: #ebebeb ;
color: #67a5cd;
padding: 80px 5px 0px 5px;
}
```

```
<div class="navbox">
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">Bad</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtwsJ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define a `margin-top` for you element
2. On `hover` reduce that margin by the value you're increasing the height of the element

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jtwsJ/2/)

```css
ul.nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    background: #cbcbcb ;
    color: #174867;
    padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
}

ul.nav li a:hover {
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ebebeb ;
    color: #67a5cd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that comes to mind is relatively positioning the element then changing the `top` property to move it up the amount that you're adding to the box.

1. Add `position: relative` and `top: 0` to the non-hover state.
2. Add `top: -66px` to the hover state.

Which would result in [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/wnEYb/2/). (Note I added extra space to the top so you could see it move upwards rather than off the screen).